# rtmfp FMS or Cirrus

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-media-server, adobe-cirrus

I want to build a small p2p chat application. However, at this stage i dont know whether i should opt for FMS development server or Cirrus. What are the principle differences between FMS and Cirrus? Does FMS have NetStream and NetGroup classes and Cirrus doesn't or vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between both:

- Cirrus - Adobe rendezvous service that does all the dirty job of connecting your P2P app users with each other. Now, after Cirrus connects the users, they can communicate using Adobe P2P RTMFP protocol which is based on UDP and therefore is fast but not 100% reliable. Perfect choice for games and applications that require low latency connection between peers. (Note: AFAIK Cirrus license does not allow to use it for commercial apps but you can use free alternative, like Cumulus, which, by the way, is an open source project).
- FMS is based on different approach. Not like RTMFP where all users connect directly to each other, FMS is a centralized server, meaning all traffic first goes through the server before reaching target users. In addition, it is based on higher level TCP protocol (100% connection reliability). Therefore it is slower and produces higher latency compared to RTMFP. FMS can be used as a fallback when Cirrus or similar rendezvous service fails to connect two users using RTMFP.

Comment: Note that an FMS server can use either RTMP or RTMFP for streaming audio/video. The only real difference between  the two protocols is that RTMP is TCP and RTMFP is UDP. You can get low latency/realtime video with FMS using RTMFP.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add that FMS can also be used as rendezvous service.